# Como filtrar com ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho dois `<select>`, ou seja, um picklist(multiselect) feito a mão.

No primeiro `<select>`, quero mostrar somente os clientes trazidos pelo `ng-repeat` mas que contenham o campo `consultaNotasDestinadas` como '1'.

No segundo `<select>`, quero mostrar somente os clientes trazidos pelo `ng-repeat` mas que contenham o campo `consultaNotasDestinadas` como '0'.

Como posso fazer isso?

Segue meu html:

```
<div class="form group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
   <select id="select1" name="select1" multiple="multiple">
     <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}" ng-click="atribuirUm($index, c)">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>
   </select>
   <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
   <select ng-model="listaEmpresas" id="select2" name="select2" multiple="multiple">
     <option selected="selected" ng-repeat="c2 in clientes2" value="{{c2.idCliente}}" ng-click="limparUm($index, c2)">{{c2.razaoSocial}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aplique o filtro diretamente via diretiva *filter*, especificando um objeto que representa as propriedades que você deseja filtrar e o valor de critério:

```
[...]
    <option ng-repeat="c in clientes | filter: { consultaNotasDestinadas : '1' }">
[...]
```

Irá exibir apenas objetos `c` cuja propriedade `consultaNotasDestinadas` tenha valor igual a `'1'`.

Exemplo funcional a seguir:

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope, $resource) {
  
  $scope.clientes = [
    { Name : 'Cliente 1', consultaNotasDestinadas : '1'},
    { Name : 'Cliente 2', consultaNotasDestinadas : '0'},
    { Name : 'Cliente 3', consultaNotasDestinadas : '1'},
    { Name : 'Cliente 4', consultaNotasDestinadas : '0'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-resource.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">

  <div ng-controller="SampleController">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Clientes com consultaNotasDestinadas = 1</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option ng-repeat="c in clientes | filter: { consultaNotasDestinadas : '1' }" value='{{c.Name}}'>{{c.Name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Clientes com consultaNotasDestinadas = 0</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option ng-repeat="c in clientes | filter: { consultaNotasDestinadas : '0' }" value='{{c.Name}}'>{{c.Name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, estou pegando este erro: Expected array but received: {}. o que posso fazer?

Comment: @LeonardoLeonardo Me parece que a fonte de dados que você está passando para a diretiva ng-repeat é um objeto, ao invés de uma coleção. Referência: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32214990/angularjs-error-filternotarray-expected-array-but-received-with-a-filter

Comment: Vou marcar correto pra resposta, pois meu problema agora é outro, o filtro funcionou, não pegava nada porque meu atributo no JS vem como null, testei com null e veio. Ai já é outra coisa, meu DTO era um boolean e no banco mysql era BIT, o mysql não tem boolean...

Comment: @LeonardoLeonardo Sempre um prazer ajudar. Sinta-se à vontade para postar tantas perguntas quanto necessitar. Suas dúvidas poderão ajudar a futuros desenvolvedores.